# Facing issue on connecting Android device to Android Studio of remote desktop via USB & Wi-Fi both

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, remote-debugging

I am trying to connect Android Device to Android Studio foe Debugging App in Remote Desktop via USB and Wi-Fi. In both way i am facing issue, for USB it is not connecting to the Remote Desktop from my Local System. But device is connecting in Local system. And for Wi-Fi I have connected with the VPN to the same network of Remote Connection but in Android Studio it is asking for connecting same Wi-Fi while I am connected to the VPN.

Kindly tell me a way that I can connect my Android Device to the Android Studio of Remote Desktop from Local System.

I am trying to connect Android Device to Android Studio for Debugging App in Remote Desktop via USB and Wi-Fi. I want to connect it.